# access modifier for protected method

Tags: java, modifier

For the protected access modifier, the method or attribute associated with it should be visible to its subclass. That's according to the definition.

But there is one thing I cannot explain here is. For example, we have the below code:
Base class:

```
package com.set.test;

public class ModifierBase {
    private int privateInt;
    int friendlyInt;
    protected int protectedInt;
    public int publicInt;

    private void displayPrivate(){
        System.out.println("displayPrivate");
    }
    void displayFriendly(){
        System.out.println("displayFriendly");
    }
    protected void displaoyProtected(){
        System.out.println("displaoyProtected");
    }
    public void displayPublic(){
        System.out.println("displayPublic");
    }
}
```

And a class extends this one in a different package.

```
package com.another;

import com.set.test.ModifierBase;
public class ModifierSubPackgeExtend extends ModifierBase{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModifierSubPackgeExtend m = new ModifierSubPackgeExtend();
        ModifierBase mb = new ModifierSubPackgeExtend();
    }
}
```

m can access both protected and public, that's cool.
However, mb cannot access the protected method or variable.

```
mb.protectedInt //is not accessable
m.protectedInt //is accessible
```

**Why is that?**

But for friendly having the same example:

```
package com.set.test;
public class ModifierExtend extends ModifierBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModifierExtend m = new ModifierExtend();
        ModifierBase mb = new ModifierExtend();
    }
}
```

Both m and mb can access the friendly modifier.

```
m.friendlyInt
mb.friendlyInt
```

They are both fine.

**Why when declared with the base class and initialize with the subclass has different access to protected vs declare and initialize both with the subclass?**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also, java has no `friendly` modifier. That's package level permission.

Comment: I no there is no friendly literal as a keyword. I am just asking why declare as base class has different access level compares to declare as subclass. Why the behavior is not the same compare to the friendly access.

Comment: There is no friendly access, only package level access. And they are in different packages.

Comment: friendly access = package access. Just calling it differently. The same thing...

Comment: I'm afraid you are mistaken. They are not the same thing at all; in C++ a friend level field has a completely different behaviour.

Comment: OK. never mind calling what is what. I just want to know why when declared with the base class and initialize with the subclass has different access to protected vs declare and initialize both with the subclass?

Comment: They are in *different* packages. Or I just don't understand your question at all; please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

protected classes, function, etc. are visible for your current class, package and subpackages. Also visible inside subclasses of your class.

Public variables – Visible to all classes.

Protected variables – Visible only to these classes which they belong, and any subclasses.

Friendly variables, the default –  No modifiers are needed, Visible to the package.

Private variables – Visible only to the class to which they belong.

for more information you can read this document : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

The protected member variable is declared in the super class, but is not accessed from the same instance.

In that case it will not be accessible, protected non-static variables can only be accessed from the subclass if it concerns the same instance.